# Integral on the solid angle of a function of the direction

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, integration

I need to compute the integral
$$\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{q}{E}n^in^jn^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}$$
where $n^i$, $n^j$ and $n^k$ are the unit vectors and $g$ is a function of the direction.

I started dividing the $d^3q$ into $d\Omega dq q^2$ but then I don't know how to proceed. Should I try by parts?

Comment: I think you can change variables to show that the integral you are interested in is proportional to a Kronecker delta function. In that case you can set $j=k$ and then sum on both sides to get a major simplification.

Comment: That is what I wanted to do. But $g$ depends on the direction as well. Do you have a hint on how to do that? thanks

Comment: How are those unit vectors being multiplied? Is the $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}$ just a single term or a sum over derivatives wrt to all 3 $x_i$ via Einstein summation convention?

Comment: I am using Einstein convention here, so the $i$ indices are summed over. Outside of the integral I have a tensorial quantity such as $T_{jk}$ so it is contracted with the other indices in the integral

Comment: Since you are dotting one of the unit vectors with the derivative vector, that part is a scalar. Hence you can actually treat the integral as a two index tensor: $I^{jk}$. And then show that $I^{ij} = I\delta^{ij}$.

Comment: Also, hold on a second... you are using notation $\vec q$ in the integral and notation $\vec x$ in the derivative. Are the unit vectors giving the direction of $\vec q$ or $\vec x$? Is the x supposed to be a q?

Comment: The unit vectors give the direction of $q$ and as strange as it could be the derivative is indeed with respect to x

Comment: The fact that g depends on the direction of the momentum q is making everything harder for me...

Comment: OK, then what I said might not be right... I have to think about how it transforms a little more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it

Comment: -1 “*g depends on the direction of the momentum q*” How do you expect to do the integral without knowing exactly *how* $\partial g/\partial x^i$ depends on $\vec q$?

Comment: *$g$ is a function of the direction* The direction of *what*?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to compute the integral
> $$\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{q}{E}n^in^jn^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}$$
> where $n^i$, $n^j$ and $n^k$ are the unit vectors and $g$ is a function of the direction.

Let's refer to the integral as $I^{jk}$ such that:
$$
I^{jk}(\vec x) = \int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{q}{E}n^in^jn^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}\;.
$$

Per OP's comments, the unit vectors in the integration are with respect to $\vec q$, but the derivative on $g$ is with respect to $\vec x$. Thus the derivative term can be taken out of the integral and we can write:
$$
I^{jk}(\vec x) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{q}{E}n^in^jn^k\;.
$$

But the above integral is zero, as seen via a change of variable $\vec q \to -\vec q$:
$$
I^{jk}(\vec x) = 0
$$

Comment: The problem is that $g$ depends on the direction of the momentum.. How can you take it outside of the integral?

Comment: You said it depends on the direction, which I took to mean the direction of $\vec x$, which is what the derivative is with respect to. If this is not the case you should edit your question to include the relevant information. @Stefano98